# rails application passenger possible errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, splunk

I have installed splunk to retrieve information from my log files and elert me when specific keyword is found. Is there any way to get possible rails errors so that I can put those as keywords??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
exceptions = []
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |o| 
  exceptions << o if (o < Exception)
end
```

This will give you a list of all exceptions, but it will be quite large. I get 390 in pure IRB, so there will probably be closer to 5 or 600 if you've required the entire Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to get that by playing around with [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/), but I like Yehuda's answer